# Why OpenCV and Qt windows don't work together in same application?

Tags: python, c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to create an application that displays some widgets a Qt window in python that controls C++ object that shows a OpenCV window.
When I call each code path alone, the widgets and the OpenCV window shows, without any issues.
However, when they are called together, neither of then are shown.

Here is my test code:

**display.cpp**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>



class Display
{
public:
    Display()
    {
        std::cout << "Display built" << std::endl;
    }

    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "Print function" << std::endl;
        cv::Mat1b mat(480, 640);
        cv::imshow("Display", mat);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(display)
{
    boost::python::class_<Display>("Display")
        .def("show", &Display::show)
    ;
};
```

**analysis.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import numpy as np
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import PySide

import threading
import time
import display

class DisplayThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        print "Starting..."
        disp = display.Display()
        disp.show()



class Analysis(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Analysis, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        img = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(100,100)).astype(np.uint8).flatten()
        qimg = PySide.QtGui.QImage(img, 100, 100, PySide.QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qimg)

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')
        self.show()        

def main():
    thread = DisplayThread()
    thread.start()
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Analysis()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my cmake file to build everything:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules)

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS python)
FIND_PACKAGE(OPENCV 2.4 REQUIRED opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_calib3d opencv_video opencv_features2d opencv_objdetect)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_LIBRARIES(${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES}) # Deprecated but so convenient!

PYTHON_ADD_MODULE(display src/display.cpp)
FILE(COPY src/analysis.py DESTINATION .)
```

If I build everything and comment the line, "thread.start()" my Qt window is displayed. In the same way, when I just comment the lines:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Analysis()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The OpenCV window shows nicely.

But both together receive an Gtk error:

```
(python:21036): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
```

And no window is shown.
I'm using the defaults packages from Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Attempting to use two different widget toolkits in the same application is always an iffy proposition. Each widget toolkit will assume that it has full control over the all-underlying X11 protocol. Hillarity ensues.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's not quite true. Qt was designed to interoperate with the glib, x11, winuser and osx event loops.

Comment: Check this: http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/11/using-opencv-3-qt-creator-3-2-qt-5-3/ if you are using Qt5 you must make sure you compiled opencv without the `WITH_QT=ON` flag